# Packing algorithm for packing rectangles into irregular space

Tags: packing

I have n rectangles each height 1 and various (integer) widths. So the rectangles are equivalent to an n-length vector of positive integers.

I have c containers each width (integer) w but whose height varies. Each container is equivalent to w rectangles of width 1 and height some non-negative integer.

So each container is equivalent to a w-length vector of non-negative integers and all c containers are equivalent to a c x w matrix M of non-negative integers.

I value the packing of each rectangle in proportion to its width. I may only pack rectangles  horizontally.

So I need for each rectangle a position for its left end in some container i.e. I need (i,j) such that when summing over all the packed rectangles the total height in container i at each position is no greater than M(i,j).

I tried using solver in Excel but it only gave a local optimum.

Am thinking something like try to place rectangles in descending length. If there is ever more than one possible position, pick the one that leaves the most options for the next size down.

Comment: Can you explain the container matrix c x w more? Or add an example of what it looks like. From your description, it seems like you may have exactly one container of each w?

Comment: Thanks Nick have edited it. E.g. Suppose 3 containers all width 4 with heights (2,2,0,0), (0,1,2,1), (2,1,1,0). The three example containers would be like the Tetris game square, T, L-shape.